# How to make preg_replace have count function for number of replaces count?

Tags: php

I have creted a preg_replace script but now i want to add count function in it!

MY CODE

```
$replace = 'ISO Burning Programs/Active@ ISO Burner 2.1.0.0/SPTDinst-v162-x86.exe';
$result=preg_replace('/[^0-9^A-Z^a-z-*… ,;_!@.{}#<>""=-^:()\[\]]/', '<br/>', $replace);
echo $result;
```

OUTPUT

```
ISO Burning Programs
Active@ ISO Burner 2.1.0.0
SPTDinst-v162-x86.exe
```

But the output i want is-

```
1 ISO Burning Programs
2 Active@ ISO Burner 2.1.0.0
3 SPTDinst-v162-x86.exe
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just do `str_replace('/', '<br/>', $replace);`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could just do this:

```
$replace = 'ISO Burning Programs/Active@ ISO Burner 2.1.0.0/SPTDinst-v162-x86.exe';
$result = explode('/', $replace);

foreach($result as $i => $value)
    printf("%d %s<br />", ++$i, $value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with `preg`, you'd have to use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/([^\/]*)(\/|$)/', function($matches){
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;
    return !empty($matches[1]) ? $count.' '.$matches[1].'<br/>' : '';
}, $replace);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    preg_replace has a count function in it, the -1 is limit (unlimited) and $count is the number of replacement. just FYI.

    $result=preg_replace('/[^0-9^A-Z^a-z-*… ,;_!@.{}#<>""=-^:()\[\]]/', '<br/>\n', $replace, -1, $count);

    $a = explode("\n", $result);
    $i=1;
foreach($a as $res)
    {
    echo $i . " " . $res;
$i++;
    }
```